# Adding DC offset to a given input

Tags: voltage, dc-offset, operational-amplifier

let me start off by saying I am a computer science student so I'm not familiar with electronics whatsoever. Anyway, I am faced with this problem:

I am given some input (say, a sine wave) centered on 0V (Peak to Peak is, say, -5V to 5V). I want to make my output signal with a Peak to Peak of 5V to 15V, how would I approach this? One attempt at the solution was the following circuit i got from googling - [image]

The circuit managed to change the DC offset but the peak to peak is not where I want it to be. Are there any other circuits I could try? I read somewhere that a non-inverting amplifier (with an op-amp) may change the offset so I will attempt that next.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What frequency is that sine wave? 40 Hz?

Comment: What's the signal feeding into?  That 1k pullup is what's sucking the life out of the signal.  It's too big.

Comment: Sorry, the frequency should be 600 Hz (It's 600 Hz in the example but I don't think the frequency matters? I could be wrong though). The signal isn't feeding into anything, im just looking at the output measured at the far right of the circuit

Comment: Perform an Internet search for an application report titled "Designing Gain and Offset in Thirty Seconds", written by Bruce Carter and published by Texas Instruments (TI document #SLOA097).

Answer (score 3):

Consider a [clamping circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamper_(electronics)).  Such a circuit can relocate the upper or lower extreme of a waveform to a predetermined voltage level.

[image]

It sounds as if the following circuit with a 5 volt battery (or floating power supply) is what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: Err, what's a 5 volt battery?

Comment: I'll make that 5.6 volts, to compensate for the diode drop. 4x 1.5V alkaline batteries plus a 5.6V zener diode and limiting resistor?

Comment: @PaulUszak Just use "alibaba 5V battery" and you will find one. Yes, I did that and immediately found two Li-Ion .

Comment: @PaulUszak Some NiCd cells are specified as 1.25 V, 4 of those would be a 5 V battery.

Comment: Has anyone ever measured the unloaded voltage of a battery with 1.5V printed on it?

Answer (score 2):

Gonna break out the ol' falstad because you used it.

The non inverting op amp circuit you mentioned looks like this:
[image]

It adds an offset equal to the voltage on the non inverting input (+), and adds some gain equal to -Rf/Rin, where Rf is the top resistor.

[image]

This is also an alternative way, but you're gonna lose some amplitude because the arrangement creates a low pass filter.

Comment: That first circuit inverts the signal.

Comment: I just built this circuit and it applies the offset but the signal is inverted, why is it inverted? I thought this was a non-inverting op amp

Comment: It is inverted because it should be inverted--it is an inverting amplifier. There is a version where it doesn't invert the signal, but you can't add a DC offset easily.

Answer (score 1):

> I am given some input (say, a sine wave) centered on 0V (Peak to Peak
>   is, say, -5V to 5V). I want to make my output signal with a Peak to
>   Peak of 5V to 15V, how would I approach this?

Instead of using the resistor in your circuit connected to +5 volts, connect it to +10 volts. This makes the average level at the output +10 volts with the 10 Vp-p sinewave superimposed on top. Thus it attains a peak of +15 volt and a trough of +5 volts. Ensure that R is a fairly high value so that the AC signal is hardly attenuated.

Something like 10 kohms should be OK for your circuit but, beware of loading the output too much - use a buffer if connecting a low impedance load.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want the AC signal going directly into your DC power source, you should replace the resistor with an inductor.

Then you would have a basic [Bias tee](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_tee).

At such a low frequency (600 Hz) your inductor would have to be quite large, however. Something like 1 H. Also, your DC supply should be centered at your mean value: 10 V.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

*Note: sorry for the crude schematic. It’s all I can do from my phone.